# python for loop returns last value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, enumerate

I have a function:

```
def devices():
    devices = []
    device = {}
    with open('devices.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        device['ip'] = line.split(';')[0].strip()
        device['name'] = line.split(';')[1].strip()

        print(device)
        devices.append(device)


print(devices)

return devices
```

File devices.txt has a next layout:

```
1.1.1.1;device-1
2.2.2.2;device-2
```

When I print device dictionary inside loop - it is ok.
However as a return I get the next list:

```
[{'ip':'2.2.2.2', 'name':'device-2'},{'ip':'2.2.2.2', 'name':'device-2'}]
```

Why? Why not all devices from the file but last one 2 times.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  If I set `my_list = [{}, {}, {}]` and run that `for` loop, each dict in `my_list` gets assigned a different value for `'id'`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either: `my_list = [{'a': 1},{'b': 2},{'c': 3}]`, using your code I get: `[{'a': 1, 'id': 0}, {'b': 2, 'id': 1}, {'c': 3, 'id': 2}]`. Please provide some example input.

Comment: This would happen if you didn't have distinct dictionaries in your list, but only multiple references to the _same_ dict.  How was your `my_list` constructed?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but still I have another problem. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question! I got a bit confused in the beginning why it wasn't working, then I realised the dic outside the loop. I usually don't use dics because of these strange problems, in your case, changing the variable when  it's already appended. Here is a simple solution for your code

```
def devices():
    devices = []
    with open('devices.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    #print(lines)
    for line in lines:
    device = {}
        device['ip'] = line.split(';')[0].strip()
        device['name'] = line.split(';')[1].strip()



    print(device)
        devices.append(device)
    print(devices)
```

(If you want to see how strange dics are, you can write `device = {}` one line before the append and your output will be:
[{'ip':'2.2.2.2', 'name':'device-2'},{}]
How the {'ip':'2.2.2.2', 'name':'device-2'} got there, no idea)

Answer (score -1):

```
def devices():
    with open('devices.txt', 'r') as file:
        return [{'ip':line.split(';')[0].strip(), 'name':line.split(';')[1].strip()} for line in file.readlines()]
print(devices())
# [{'name': 'device-1', 'ip': '1.1.1.1'}, {'name': 'device-2', 'ip': '2.2.2.2'}]
```